# Nagios: check if folder size increases by at least 1kb

Tags: nagios

Is there a way to check the size of a folder increases by at least 1kb every hour? I can't seem to find any plug-ins that do this out of the box.

My Nagios experience is very little I'm afraid so I'll be needing some step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do, you will need to store measured sizes somewhere, to compare them later. Since Nagios does not have any detailed state data that can be sent to the plugin on next execution.

Alternatively you could use a graphing solution and monitor the changes, but not that easy as well...

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FILE-SIZE-TESTING) allows you to do that. If you want, use `nagios` to check if `monit` is active. `monit` can send you a mail if something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was writing a small C# console app that does the necessary checks and saves the state in a text file. Then use Nagios to run that app every hour.